# Docker container gracefully shutting down automatically after a week

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am having an issue related to the Docker container which running a multi stage docker image comprising of nginx and bunch of html files.  The problem is, it is shutting down gracefully after running for a week or 2 weeks. The signal it receives is : `signal 3 (SIGQUIT) received, shutting down` .

The list of containers running:

```
1a68ecd3b68f   angular-nginx-web    "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   14 hours ago   Up 14 hours   80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:49162->8002/tcp, :::49162->8002/tcp   web
600c7583e1cc   nginx:alpine                                                                 "/docker-entrypoint.…"   14 hours ago   Up 14 hours   0.0.0.0:8000->80/tcp, :::8000->80/tcp                 nginx
fd9c765aedc1   express-node-backend   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   14 hours ago   Up 14 hours   0.0.0.0:49161->8001/tcp, :::49161->8001/tcp           rest
```

The container name which is gracefully shutting down is `web`

Docker-compose file:

```
services:
  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    image: nginx:alpine
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    command: nginx -g "daemon off;"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/production/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    networks:
      - prod
  web:
    container_name: web
    image: angular-nginx-web
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/web:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - type: bind 
        source: ./env/production/web_base_settings/settings.json
        target: /usr/share/nginx/html/assets/settings/settings.json
    ports:
      - "8002"
    networks:
      - prod

  rest:
    container_name: rest
    image: 
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - env/production/rest.env
    ports:
      - "8001"
    networks:
      - prod
```

Dockerfile for `angular-nginx-web` image:

```
# Stage 1

# Build target base #
#####################
FROM node:6-alpine AS base
WORKDIR /angular-nginx-web
COPY package*.json  ./
COPY .git/ ./.git/
RUN apk add --no-cache git && \
    npm install
COPY . /angular-nginx-web
RUN npm run build && \
    rm -rf /node_modules

# Stage 2

FROM nginx:alpine as server
WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html
RUN rm -rf ./*
COPY --from=base /angular-nginx-web/dist .
ENTRYPOINT ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

The logs received :

```
<ip> - - [10/Mar/2022:17:23:57 +0000] "HEAD /assets/misc/connectcheck.txt HTTP/1.0" 200 0 "http://<ip>:8000/angular-web/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36" "10.80.240.47"
2022/03/11 02:12:38 [notice] 1#1: signal 3 (SIGQUIT) received, shutting down
2022/03/11 02:12:38 [notice] 9#9: exiting
2022/03/11 02:12:38 [notice] 7#7: gracefully shutting down
2022/03/11 02:12:38 [notice] 7#7: exiting
2022/03/11 02:12:38 [notice] 7#7: exit
2022/03/11 02:12:38 [notice] 8#8: gracefully shutting down
2022/03/11 02:12:38 [notice] 8#8: exiting
2022/03/11 02:12:38 [notice] 8#8: exit
2022/03/11 02:12:38 [notice] 1#1: signal 17 (SIGCHLD) received from 9
2022/03/11 02:12:38 [notice] 1#1: cache manager process 9 exited with code 0
2022/03/11 02:12:38 [notice] 1#1: signal 29 (SIGIO) received
2022/03/11 02:12:38 [notice] 1#1: signal 17 (SIGCHLD) received from 7
2022/03/11 02:12:38 [notice] 1#1: worker process 7 exited with code 0
2022/03/11 02:12:38 [notice] 1#1: signal 29 (SIGIO) received
2022/03/11 02:12:38 [notice] 1#1: signal 17 (SIGCHLD) received from 8
2022/03/11 02:12:38 [notice] 1#1: worker process 8 exited with code 0
2022/03/11 02:12:38 [notice] 1#1: exit
```

Can anybody please help. I am relatively new to Docker and finding it hard to figure out the reason for this graceful shutdown.

Comment: Run `docker ps -a` to get id of the exited container and then `docker inspect <id>` and add the json to your question

Comment: Also posted on https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-container-gracefully-shutting-down-automatically-after-a-week/122774

Answer (score 1):

are you by any chance running the docker commands under a rootless docker context that you run from your own user?

If that is the case, `systemd` might be the culprit. `systemd` kills processes started under a user automatically after a certain amount of time whent he user session ends.

### The Solution

Enable linger mode or configure `systemd` to not kill user processes, or both.

```bash
sudo loginctl enable-linger $USER
```

Just to be sure, edit `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` and add the following
lines to the end.

```ini
UserStopDelaySec=infinity
KillUserProcesses=no
```

Reboot your machine for the new config to take effect.

```
sudo reboot
```

From the [docs](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/systemd/logind.conf.5.en.html):

> `KillUserProcesses=`
>
> Takes a boolean argument. Configures whether the processes of a user should be killed when the user logs out. If true, the scope unit corresponding to the session and all processes inside that scope will be terminated. If false, the scope is "abandoned", see systemd.scope(5), and processes are not killed. **Defaults to "no"**, but see the options KillOnlyUsers= and KillExcludeUsers= below.

Unless of course linger mode is enabled, [documented here](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/systemd/loginctl.1.en.html#:%7E:text=enable%2Dlinger%20%5BUSER...%5D)

> `enable-linger [USER...], disable-linger [USER...]`
>
> Enable/disable user lingering for one or more users. If enabled for a specific user, a user manager is spawned for the user at boot and kept around after logouts. This allows users who are not logged in to run long-running services. Takes one or more user names or numeric UIDs as argument. If no argument is specified, enables/disables lingering for the user of the session of the caller.

I [wrote a blog about it](https://omranjamal.me/blog/005-keep-docker-rootless-alive/) with a bit more detail if you want to check it out.